# How to access array elements that are defined in another array of Mongoose scheme object Array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, mongoose

This is the `User` schema in mongoose:

```js
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  Addtasks: [
    {
      topic: String,
      words: Number,
      keywords: String,
      website: String,
      otherdetails: String,
      exampleRadios: String,
      deadline: Date,
      Date: String,
      fileName: String,
      Bigpaths: [],
    },
  ],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I want to use/access the `Bigpaths` array, which is defined inside the `Addtasks` array, which is defined in `User`. Data is already are there in `mongoDB`, which I have inserted via `UI` page. I am  trying the following code but I am getting this error in console:

```js
data.Addtasks[Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length - 2].Bigpaths.forEach(
  (element) => {
    // ...
    }
)
```

as

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Bigpaths' of undefined
    at \Desktop\grumpytext\routes\index.js:99:71
```

Code:

```js
const { files } = req;
User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }, function (error, data) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Three');
  } else if (data) {
    if (Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length > 1) {
      data.Addtasks[Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length - 2].Bigpaths.forEach(
        (element) => {
          files.forEach((currentElement) => {
            if (element.name == currentElement.filename) {
              files.pull(currentElement.filename);
            }
          });
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

How to resolve this error or how to access all the elements of `Bigpaths` array so that I can iterate it with `forEach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure here, but I think you need to [populate](https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7) Addtasks prior to manipulating it:

```
const files = req.files;
User.findOne({email:req.user.email}).populate('Addtasks').exec((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Three");
    }  
    else 
    {
        if(data)
        {
            if(Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length > 1)
            {
                console.log("Addtasks count: " + Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length);
                data.Addtasks[Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length - 2].Bigpaths.forEach(element => {
                    files.forEach(currentElement => {
                    if(element.name == currentElement.filename)
                    {
                        files.pull(currentElement.filename);
                    }
                    })
            });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please notice the log `console.log("Addtasks count: " + Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length);` - in case the solution does not work, I advise to add some prints, especially to check if the count of elements is as expected or properties within an object are fine.

Comment: And what is the count of Addtasks?